# Change group of only cache folders, recursive

Tags: sles, groups, recursive

I have a document root folder and I want to cange the group of only the cache directories. How can I do this recursive?

The cache directories are always below `templates/html`, and I want to change it to `wwwrun:www`.

The folder structure looks like:

```
/blocks/element1/templates/html/cache1    root:root   <- this
/blocks/element1/lib/file.html            root:root
/blocks/element1/lib/file-xy.html         root:root
/blocks/element2/templates/html/cache1    root:root   <- this
/blocks/element2/templates/html/cache2    root:root   <- this
/blocks/element2/lib/file.html            root:root
/blocks/element2/img/icon.png             root:root
/blocks/element3/templates/html/cache2    root:root   <- this
/blocks/element3/logo.jpg                 root:root
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

running

```
find . -type d -name "cache*" -exec chown -R wwwrun:www {} \;
```

inside templates/html should do it.

Comment: I run it inside `/blocks/`.